# How to handle unhandled exception throw in monix onErrorHandle

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, monix

I am using monix tasks and i am trying to catch a Throwable and then convert to a custom error. I have removed/changed the code to be simple and relevant. This is the code (question follows after the code snippet):

```
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest
import monix.reactive.Observable
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf
import monix.eval.Task
import com.mypackage.Response


private[this] def handler(
      request: HttpRequest,
      body: Observable[ByteBuf]
  ): Task[Response] = {

    val localPackage = for {
      failfast <- Task.eval(1 / 0)
    } yield failfast

    // Failure case.
    localPackage.onErrorRecoverWith {
        case ex: ArithmeticException =>
          print(s"LOG HERE^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
          return Task.now(
            Response(HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                     None,
                     None)
          )
    }.runAsync

    // Success case.
    localPackage.map { x => 
       x match {
        case Right(cool) =>
          Response(
            HttpResponseStatus.OK,
            None,
            cool
          )
        case Left(doesntmatter) => ???
      }
  }
}
```

I am able to see the print statement but the expected `Task.now(Response(...` is not being returned. Instead the method that calls the handler method is throwing an error. How do i make it return the `Task[Response]` ?

The success case works, the failure case does not.

Edit #1 : Fix errors in scala code.

Edit #2 This is how I fixed it.

```
    // Success case.
    localPackage.map { x => 
       x match {
        case Right(cool) =>
          Response(
            HttpResponseStatus.OK,
            None,
            cool
          )
        case Left(doesntmatter) => ???
      }
  }.onErrorRecoverWith {
        case ex: ArithmeticException =>
          print(s"LOG HERE^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
          return Task.now(
            Response(HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                     None,
                     None)
          )
    }
```

I was thinking in terms of future and forgot the `lazy eval` nature of task. Also I understood how the `CancellableFuture` value was being discarded in the failure task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several problems with your sample.

For one this code isn't valid Scala:

```
val localPackage = for {
  failfast <- 1 / 0
} yield failfast
```

I guess you meant `Task.eval(1 / 0)`.

Also `onErrorHandle` does not have a `Task` as a return type, you were probably thinking of `onErrorHandleWith`. And it's a pretty bad idea to give it a partial function (i.e. a function that can throw exceptions due to matching errors) — if you want to match on that error, then better alternatives are `onErrorRecover` and `onErrorRecoverWith`, which take partial functions as arguments.

So here's a sample:

```
import monix.eval._
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

val task = Task.eval(1 / 0).onErrorRecoverWith {
  case _: ArithmeticException => Task.now(Int.MinValue)
}

task.runAsync.foreach(println)
//=> -2147483648
```

Hope this helps.